# How to execute a function and track outbound link on page exit using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, tracking, outbound

I want to execute few functions before the page just exits such as logging page exit time.

The `onbeforeunload` event when used shows a pop-up which I don't want.

Somehow when an outbound link is clicked, it should enter a function, fetch the link `href`, execute and then exit the page.

Without using `JQuery`.

Is this possible?

Comment: why does `onbeforeunload` show a popup for you? You must be adding that in somewhere.

Comment: The "beforeunload" event does not show a pop-up. It's just an event... It's your event handler that calls the pop-up.

Comment: As per my experience you can't browser cannot wait until enter a function featch a link and wait for responce and then exit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
        //do your stuff
        return true;
    });
};
```

give that a shot.

If you need information about the link itself, use the `this` construct.  Specifically:

```
this.href
```

will get you the link address.

http://jsfiddle.net/6PEmj/5/

Comment: how do I get the outbound link? (value of the `href`)

Comment: This is not working. The browser changes the page before the script executes. There must be a delay given somewhere.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Is it something the user should see?

Comment: Actually I need to record the outbound link. My question is, when the click event occurs on a link how will it get into the for loop?

Comment: your `oldOnclick` thing won't work. Never try to that, just use the advanced `addEventListener()` method

Comment: @Bergi - It absolutely does, and will work.  Because javascript is a silly language that will let you do whatever you want. http://jsfiddle.net/6PEmj/2/

Comment: thanks both of yu. both worked. I had just forgotten to put then in onload.

Comment: yeah i did that `getAttribut('this.href')` but for `href='index.html'` gives only index.html. how to get the full url? (it would not give me sub directories in the case of relative path.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16702/discussion-between-neil-martin-and-frankiethekneeman)

Answer (score 1):

`onbeforeunload` only alerts when a return value is specified.

Try using this to detect when an outbound link is clicked:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    i = a.length,
    domain = new RegExp(location.href.match(/(^.*)\./)[1]),
    onLeave = function () {
        if (!domain.test(this.href)) {
            alert('Leaving!');
        }
    };

while (i--) {
    a[i].onclick = onLeave;
}
```